# Compare timestamp and date in angular

Tags: angular, date, timestamp

I want to compare date and timestamp. Here dates is array of dates and dateTimestamp is array of timestamps, what I want is that if the date matches increment a count else not.Can anyone help me out.
What I tried is -

```
this.dates.forEach(e => {
     dateTimestamp.forEach(f => {
       if(e == f) {
         console.log('here', c++);
       } else {
         console.log('hyyy', c);
       }
     });
   });
```

[image: sample data]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: sample data would be really helpful for us

Comment: @StepUp sorry for the inconvenience. I have added data screenshot.

Comment: @ANUSHKAGARG it is better to show your data like text, not images:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
this.dates.forEach(e => {
const dateA: any = new Date(e);
     dateTimestamp.forEach(f => {
       const dateB: any = new Date(f);
       if(dateA == dateB) {
         console.log('here', e);
       } else {
         console.log('hyyy', f);
       }
     });
   });
```

Comment: while consoling dateA and dateB 'invalid date' is coming.

Comment: can you provide https://stackblitz.com/ demo or add dates and dateTimestamp array.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert timestamp into date object using

```
 new Date(13456543);
```

and then compare using the function below

```
calcDateDifference(date1, date2) {
        let a = moment(date1);
        let b = moment(date2);
        const diff = a.diff(b, "days");
        return diff;
    }
```

where date1 and date2 are Date objects;